How to fscanf `1/2` as `0.5` from a .dad file in C
I have a .dad file with the content
1/2

I wish to read from the file and save the value 0.5 into a double using fscanf, but the method reads it as 1.000.

To be completely clear, here is the code and the output:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    
    /* Open the file */
    FILE * file ;
    file = fopen ("test.dad", "r");
    if ( file == NULL ){
        printf("Error opening %s\n", ".dad file."); 
        return 1;
    }

    /* Import data to x */
    double x = 0;
    fscanf(file, "%lf", &x);      
    fclose(file); 

    /* Print x */
    printf("%lf\n", x);
    return 0;
}

Output:
1.000000


fscanf doesn't understand the notation (number)/(number). You'll have to build it yourself.

fscanf was told to read a floating point value. It read the 1, and the next character was non-numeric (/), so it stopped, and properly read the value 1.0. You need to read the expression and implement the math yourself to divide 1 by 2 to get 0.5.

If you know that there are two numbers separated by a /, then you can read in both numbers separately and then perform the division yourself.

Is it guaranteed that there are always two integers separated by a / and nothing else (not even spaces)? Or are you asking how to handle any kind of mathematical expression, for example 5 * 3 / 2 + 5? Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

You get 1.0 because it only successfully parses 1 from 1/2. It has no clue what to do with /. What you need in this case is to read two integers separated by / and then divide those using double precision.
Example:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[] = "1/2";
    int num, denom;
    if (sscanf(line, "%d/%d", &num, &denom) == 2) {
        double x = (double)num / (double)denom;
        printf("%lf\n", x);                        // prints 0.5
    }
}



scanf does not evaluate any expressions. It only reads the (in your case float) constant

If you want to evaluate expressions entered as strings you need to use 3rd party libraries - for example tinuExpr


example:
https://godbolt.org/z/v1EM4deYh
int main(void)
{
    char str[100];
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    printf("Result: %f\n", te_interp(str, 0));
}

when you enter 1/2 the result will be 0.500000
Your expression: https://godbolt.org/z/Ma6bGfhrf
